# Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. for firefox navegator

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I using selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1, firefox 47.0. I have two nodes, one with for firefox other for chrome, The configuration in chrome work ok.

The selenium_grid.bat is configured the following way

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -port 7776 -hub http://x.x.x.x:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS",maxInstances=3,maxSession=1
```

For create instance of navigator

```
private void createBrowserInstance() {
        switch (environmentHandler.getTestBrowser().toLowerCase()) {
            case "firefox":
                browCapab = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                browserType = BrowserType.FIREFOX;
                browCapab.setBrowserName("firefox");
                browCapab.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                break;
```

But when execute the test is shown the error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the
>   remote browser. It may have died. Driver info: driver.version:
>   FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true,
>   version=47.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   8e9a0c74-4b64-4afd-a824-36984af93883 Command duration or timeout: 2.23
>   seconds

Please, someone can help me with this error. Thanks.

Comment: That is a really old set up . Any specific reason for the same.

Comment: I've been using this same configuration for a while now, only with chrome, now for firefox, it's giving me problems.